# What does the output of explicitly printing an array in java mean?

Tags: java

First of all, yes, I know I have to iterate through an array and print its elements one by one in order to actually "print" an array. I was just wondering what the output of explicitly printing an array such as in the code below actually means. My guess is that it's the memory location of the array?

I know it's a fairly newbie question but I'm new to java (and coding in general) so please enlighten me.

```
public class Tests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] strArray = {"1", "2", "3"};
        System.out.println(strArray);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `Arrays.toString` to print the array without manually having to write the loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140402/438992

Answer (score 5):

The `println(Object)` method invokes `Object::toString` on its parameter, so you are really asking about the meaning of the `toString` method on arrays.  And arrays do not override `toString`, so the result comes from the implementation of `toString` in `Object`.

The default implementation of `toString` includes the name of the object's class and a numeric representation derived from its object identity.  In the absence of a better `toString`, this allows you to see the object's type, as well as be able to differentiate different instances (since they'll have different identities).  This is a "least common denominator" approach; it is a reasonable minimum the system can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It's the default toString method of Object class.
It's the name of the class plus @ plus the return value of hashCode method, which may be implemented differently in every class.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I suggest you add that interesting fact about `identityHashCode` to your Answer here. I had never noticed that method.